# Using created Tensorflow CNN models in Windows?

Tags: tensorflow, windows-7-x64

I am working on character recognition. I used to work previously in matlab and my segmentation code is created in matlab installed in Windows. Rightnow, I am experimenting CNN using Tensorflow in Ubuntu. Is there anyway to load and test the created Tensorflow CNN models inside Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to run TensorFlow on Windows now is using a VM/Docker, steps outlined [here](https://gist.github.com/ericjang/959c03168c0bdfac1ca3).

However, if you are just interested in running inferences (without training/updating your model), you could take a look at [tfdeploy](https://github.com/riga/tfdeploy) which exports your TensorFlow code to Numpy code, so that you only depend on Numpy.

Comment: Thank you Fematich .... I think tfdeploy is what I needed for now.. Will see in detail and update the status.